# Extract month from year-month numbers array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array, e.g.,

```js
a = [20208, 20209, 202010, 20206]
```

I need only the last digit(s) (the month) of each number, e.g.,

```js
a = [8, 9, 10, 6]
```

How do I do that with JavaScript?

Comment: why `10` instead of `0`

Comment: because from those digits i need months like October

Comment: how to get months from it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If month is at the end of the year in array then simply loop over item and slice item after year, you will get the month.

```js
const a = [20208, 20209, 202010, 20206, 202011]
const t = a.map(item => +`${item}`.slice(4))
console.log(t)
```

Answer (score 1):

Being numeric values, another option is to use the mod operator rather than slicing:

```js
const a = [20208, 20209, 202010, 20206,20218];
console.log(a.map(x => (x%100)>12?x%10:x%100));
```